# impersonation is failing in running the Installed Application After finishing the Setup

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, impersonation

I have a small application and a wix setup for that. It automatically downloads the application update from server and launch it in reinstall mode and finish it launch the updated exe file.
But setup is showing an error `Debug assertion failed` in launching the exe.
if I say ignore then it works fine. 
So it is happening only with the `Standard User`. It seems to be that `impersonation` is failing.

Comment: Why do you think impersonation is failing? Impersonation runs the action as the standard user.

Answer (score 0):

Is the MSI a Minor Upgrade?  Does the upgrade work?

I'm not sure what the impersonation angle is.  I've done this pattern before and I launch the app from the Setup Complete dialog in the UI sequence. In this scenario it's an immediate custom action ( invoked from a DoAction ControlEvent ) and no impersonation is involved.